# How to dynamically change height of div.ReactVirtualized__Masonry__innerScrollContainer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm using the React-virtualized package, Masonry component.

My problem is with the `<div class="ReactVirtualized__Masonry__innerScrollContainer">` element.

When I load a list of 50 items, then filter that list down to five items, the height of this `div` doesn't shrink or change at all.  For instance, at 50 items, the element is set to `<div class="ReactVirtualized__Masonry__innerScrollContainer" style="... height='5000px' ...">`, and when the list gets filtered to five items, the height in this div doesn't shrink to, say 500px.

Consequently, there's 4500px of white space below my five items and above the page footer.  This extra whitespace makes for a poor user experience.

I'm using:

react@16.4.1

react-virtualized@9.18.5

redux@3.7.2

This div is a child of the `<Masonry>` component, and I don't see how I can hook into it via a callback and tell it to update when the list item count changes.

Can somebody please tell me how to make this div's height change when the list gets smaller after being filtered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you filter your list down from 50 items to 5 items, you also need to clear your `CellMeasurerCache`, reset your `cellPositioner` created with `createMasonryCellPositioner`, and `clearCellPositions` on your Masonry [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) ([Official CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/7y66p25qv6)).

```
cache.clearAll();
cellPositioner.reset(cellPositionerConfig);
this.masonryRef.clearCellPositions();
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was a huge help!